# CDE Dashboard editor does not open files

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I have the following problem with the CDE Dashboard Editor:

1- Start a file from scratch.

2- I apply a template.

3 -I preview and it looks exactly like the template.

[image]

4- I save the file.

5- When I open the Dashboard, I see the following error:

[image]

[image]

PS: Also note that the option to edit does not appear in the file browser.

What could be failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a linux problem and the java version installed. Looking at the log file, there was a library not found error.

PD: Fix it with the apt-get install.

Comment: Hi, What did you install? I don't see an error in log. But I have same issue in ubuntu 20.04 and openjdk 8

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a normal behavior. And how comes you can preview the dashboard it being saved at the beginning ?

My question is, which version of bi-server are you using ?

If it is the enterprise edition, make sure to review the activation process of CDE since the Edit button has to appear. This could help : https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0R0/CTools/Activate_CDE
If after that, the button still doesn't appear, follow this link https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/195443-Installing-marketpace-in-Pentaho-6-0-EE/ to know how to activate the marketplace, and then, reinstall the CDE plugin.

If it is the enterprise edition, just reinstall the CDE plugin.

Finally, the error that is displayed when you open the dashboard seems to be related to requireJs integration. It is not supposed be a problem, but you can uncheck the support of RequiredJs in the dashboards settings when you create it. And please check the log files, they can be a little more verbose about what's going on.

Hope it could help.